# Is it possible to get a clean WSP package from a list?

Tags: list

I have a list sitting on a SharePoint site. Someone made a quick change to the list without updating the package. Now it is my job to incorporate these changes into the package.

My package is well structured:

SiteColumns, ContentTypes, and ofc the list definition and schema.

How can I generate at least site columns and content types from this list sitting in production?

Is there a tool I can use, or a build in method, or using SP Designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try using [SP Manager 2010](http://spm.codeplex.com/) tool

LINK :http://spm.codeplex.com/

Comment: I managed to look at the xml with this tool, very useful. It does give you a sharepoint "already bastardized" version of the xml, for example it references lists by id, not by url (as per my created wsp package). There were also fields added. But overall it did help me get the job done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the publishing features activated, you could save you site as template.  The resulting package, which is by the way a .wsp package, will contain all the definition for all the content types, the site columns, etc., that your site contains.

You could then re-import that .wsp into a new Visual Studio project, resulting in a well structured project with all your artifacts.

Comment: Sounds good in theory, and that's the textbook solution, but it gave me an error during the save operation. Some column wouldn't export.